# How to loop on array of string

Tags: linux, go, makefile, gnu-make, gnu

I've command line tool which implemented  with golang, which works OK.
I want to execute some command that should provide list of strings

```
apps := $(shell fxt run apps)
apps:
    @echo $(apps) is called
```

in the terminal I see the following while executing `make` (which is totally fine)

```
[app1 app2] is called
```

Since the command `fxt run apps` return array of string (`var apps []string`)

My question is how can I **loop over** the `apps`
variable?

the data which is returned by the command is fine, but now I need to take this list (app1... appN)  and loop over it, the issue which is not clear to me, how can I loop over array of strings?

*special case* is if in the list of theloop I got `app7` how should do a fork in the code for example if(app7) prints `mvn clean install`

**example.**

for each app (in the app list) I need to run command

`go test ./...`

But for app7 in need to run

`mvn clean install`

and for app10

`yarn`

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.  It would be much more clear if you included the actual output of the makefile you show above, then describe clearly why that output is wrong and what output you would prefer to see.  Also it would be good to specify any special cases you need to deal with.

Comment: @MadScientist - Done, please have a look

Comment: Does the output of the `fxt` program include the square brackets (`[]`)?  If you had more elements would it show `[app1 app2 app3 app4] is called`?

Comment: @MadScientist - yes exactly it looks like `[app1 app2 app3 appN] is called`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to run your loop inside make itself or in the recipe which is in fact executing a shell? Here you have both!

Remark: I replace the executed command to test it myself. Here I use `ls` to fill my array.

```
apps := $(shell ls)

#looping in make itself
$(foreach var,$(apps),$(info In the loop running with make: $(var)))

#loop in shell inside recipe 
go:
    @for v in $(apps) ; do \
        echo inside recipe loop with sh command: $$v ; \
    done
```

Output:

```
In the loop running with make: a
In the loop running with make: b
In the loop running with make: c
In the loop running with make: Makefile
inside recipe loop with sh command: a
inside recipe loop with sh command: b
inside recipe loop with sh command: c
inside recipe loop with sh command: Makefile
```

Comment: `In the loop running with make: [app
In the loop running with make: app2]
`

Comment: the array is there, how can I omit the array `[' and this `]` ?

Comment: even if I've 100 apps inside, I need to remove the first and the last `[]`

Comment: well, this is not a new question ...:) i didnt edit my question , in the question I wrote that I've array of strings and this is the issue here ...

Comment: but as you suggest i will open a new question : )

Comment: as you suggest:)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52308564/how-to-loop-on-strings-and-remove-the-string-array

Comment: btw, regard you answer here which is more `make `  native way ? the first loop or the second inside `recipe` ?

Comment: @JennyM: This is only a question of your requirements. If you want to create variables, expressions or new recipes within make itself inside your loop, you have to use the "make loop". If you only need the vars inside the recipes, you can use the loop inside the recipe.