# How to loop on strings and remove the string array

Tags: linux, unix, makefile, gnu-make, gnu

I've the following code inside `make` file which gets from command array of strings

```
apps := $(shell fxt run apps)


go:
    @for v in $(apps) ; do \
        echo inside recipe loop with sh command: $$v ; \
    done
```

The command returns array like `[app1 app2 appN]`  (could be many apps inside)
But I need it to be `app1 app2 appN` , any idea how to remove the array `[]` ?

when I run make I got the following

```
inside recipe loop with sh command: [app
inside recipe loop with sh command: app2]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simple can use `subst` command with empty replacement part to remove parts of your variable content like this:

```
apps := $(shell ls)

#add []
apps := [ $(apps) ]
$(info Apps: $(apps))

# replace [ with nothing -> remove it
apps := $(subst [ ,,$(apps))

# replace ] with nothing -> remove it
apps := $(subst ],,$(apps))
$(info Apps: $(apps))
```

or using `filer-out` with:

```
apps :=$(filter-out [ ], $(apps))
```

Instead the two replacement functions. Important: Keep a `space` between the brakets, as `filter-out` needs a list of words. So you have 2 words in the pattern part of the command here.
Output:

```
Apps: [ a b c Makefile ]
Apps: a b c Makefile
```

If the input has no space between `[` and the first word, you have to use the `subst` command.

Maybe you like to concatenate both expressions in one ( but less readable ):

```
    apps := $(subst ],,$(subst [,,$(apps)))
```

Comment: thanks, could it be in one line ? instead of two subset ?

Comment: congratulation for 10K :)

Comment: @JennyM: Thanks for the needed votes;). I added a one-liner to my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) , the problem is that I dont have it like `[ app1 app2 ]`  i've it like `[app1 app2]` , there is not option to use it like this ? currenlty the filter not worknig ...

Comment: @JennyM: Then you have to use the `subst` command with two lines. I see no chance to get this in one line. Ok, you can concatenate both with: `apps := $(subst ],,$(subst [,,$(apps)))`

Comment: I've additional question which is somehow related , i'll open new one ?

Comment: @JennyM: Don't know the question :-) Give it a chance!